# Can Typescript define a string literal type that contains an arbitrary number of substring literal types in any order?

Tags: typescript, types

If I have string literal types `Hello` and `World`, I can write a string literal type that contains both of them as

```
type ContainsSubstrings = `${string}Hello${string}World${string}` | `${string}World${string}Hello${string}`;
```

Is it possible to achieve this for an arbitrary number of substrings in an arbitrary order?

I want to enforce that a SQL string contains all parameterized keys from an object.

edit: To clarify, I am wondering if a generic type is possible that can take an arbitrary list of strings and enforce that they are all substrings of a string literal type.

Comment: Do you care about overlap (e.g., does `"ABC"` contain both `"AB"` and `"BC"`)?  The intersection type in the answer below doesn't.

Comment: Strictly the type I'm looking for should not contain overlap. However for my purposes (ensuring a SQL string contains all parameters), I don't think I need to be concerned with that edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use intersection types that says it must match both string patterns.

```
type X = `${string}a${string}` & `${string}b${string}`;

// Valid
let x: X = 'xaxbx';
x = 'xbxax';

// Invalid
x = 'xbx';
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Though, doesn't this rely on a finite and known number of substrings? i.e. defining type `X` involves manually defining all intersections. I am wondering if it's possible to define a generic type that would intersect an arbitrary number of substring patterns.

Comment: Yes, you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZyZ4N).

Comment: Wow, it'll take me a minute to grok this. Thank you everyone for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
type Wild = 'Hello'|'World';
type ContainsSubstrings = `${string}${Wild}${string}${Wild}${string}`;
```

Typescript will interpret this as

```
`${string}Hello${string}Hello${string}`|
`${string}Hello${string}World${string}` | 
`${string}World${string}Hello${string}` | 
`${string}World${string}World${string}`
```

I am not sure if there is a simple way to not allow repetitions though.